# How to resolve the "Direct object instantiation (object of \Zend_Db_Expr) is discouraged in Magento 2"?

Tags: magento2, query, orm

I am getting warning as

> "Direct object instantiation (object of \Zend_Db_Expr) is discouraged
>   in Magento2"

when I did `MEQP2.`

Please anyone can help me to resolve this warning.

I am getting issue in below line.

> $Qry = $connection->select()
>               ->from($this->resourceConfig->getTable($tableName), [new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')])
>               ->where('store=?', $storeId);

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about this, but I think you can use factories for the zend classes also.

Try this:

Have this member in your class:

```
private $zendExprFactory;
```

And add this in your constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Zend_Db_ExprFactory $zendExprFactory,
    ....
) {
   ....
   $this->zendExprFactory = $zendExprFactory;
   ....
}
```

Now (If I'm right) you should be able to create the zend_db_expr instance like this:

```
$expr = $this->zendExprFactory->create(['expression' => 'COUNT(*)']);
```

and your code should look like this:

```
$Qry = $connection->select()->from(
     $this->resourceConfig->getTable($tableName), 
     [$expr]
 )->where('store=?', $storeId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Zend_Db_Expr`, you can use `\Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\Expression`

**Like**

```
use Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\Expression;

class Yourclass
{

public function test()
{
....
$Qry = $connection->select() ->from($this->resourceConfig->getTable($tableName), [new Expression('COUNT(*)')]) ->where('store=?', $storeId);
....
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera,still warning is showing

Comment: what error throw.right now?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;` in my module with `Zend_Db_Expr`